# Passing instance method as default argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Maybe this is a bit funky, but I want to pass a callable instance method as a default variable to an instance method of the same class.

```py
from typing import Callable

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hello, my name is", self.name)

    def greet(self, func: Callable=say_hi):
        func()

p = Person("Guido")
p.greet()
```

With the above solution `self` is not passed to the instance method.
Replacing `func: Callable=say_hi` with `func: Callable=self.say_hi` and `self` is not yet defined.

Comment: if you know it is an instance method? why are you passing it? You can access it inside greet like `self.say_hi`, if you still insist then you can d0 `p.greet(p.say_hi)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do assignment in the function itself:

```py
def greet(self, func: Callable = None):
    func = self.say_hi if func is None else func
    func()
```

Suggestion by `@blhsing` in the comments below is to use this (tho being explicit is kinda better than implicit, but this will work too):

```py
func = func or self.say_hi
```

Comment: Or `func = func or self.say_hi` if you like it shorter. (Too bad there's no equivalent of the `||=` operator of Ruby in Python.)